# get_posts by post_parent returns empty array

Tags: wordpress

The following code returns an empty array even though I know there are posts that have the given `post_parent` id:

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent'      => 211167,
);

$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); 
$data->subfolder_count = sizeof( $posts_array );
```

I have tried using the cli and gotten the same result

```
(12:05:29) mu-plugins/$ wp post get 211169
+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                 | Value                                |
+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+
| ID                    | 211169                               |
| post_author           | 12449                                |
| post_date             | 2016-08-14 11:21:26                  |
| post_date_gmt         | 2016-08-14 16:21:26                  |
| post_content          |                                      |
| post_title            | SubFolder Two                        |
| post_excerpt          |                                      |
| post_status           | publish                              |
| comment_status        | closed                               |
| ping_status           | closed                               |
| post_password         |                                      |
| post_name             | subfolder-two                        |
| to_ping               |                                      |
| pinged                |                                      |
| post_modified         | 2016-08-14 11:21:26                  |
| post_modified_gmt     | 2016-08-14 16:21:26                  |
| post_content_filtered |                                      |
| post_parent           | 211167                               |
| guid                  | [redacted]                           |
| menu_order            | 0                                    |
| post_type             | [redacted]                           |
| post_mime_type        |                                      |
| comment_count         | 0                                    |
+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+

(12:05:40) mu-plugins/$ wp post list --post_parent=211167
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| ID | post_title | post_name | post_date | post_status |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

If you can tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Default_Usage) fetches only posts with the post type `post` by default. Since you redacted the `post_type` I assume it's a custom post type. Add the correct `post_type` to your arguments.

Comment: Thanks Gerald.  You're absolutely right.  I came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `post_type` is required.  I changed my code to include the `post_type` instead of just `post_parent` and got the results I was looking for.